# Regex java predefined number of slash in url

Tags: java, regex, url

I have a url string as theese
http://www.domain.it/aaa/007585100-5/aaa.html
or http://aaa.domain.it/aaa/aaa/aaa.html

with this regex java `^.*(domain.it).*(.html){1}$` i match the second url but not the first. In addition my regex is not accurate.

Can also divide the regex in two regex separated. The one or two regex must exclude from match the url like aaa.domain.it/

P.S. the string "aaa" in url's can be a random string composed by 1..N char [a-z0-9].

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is it that you want to match and what do you not want to match?  Your current regex will match `http://example.com/domain/it#html`.  Is that intentional?

Comment: It seems to match both: [demo](http://fiddle.re/hqp36).

Comment: That regex matches both - [Java code](https://ideone.com/l2of1q), or do you *want* to match the second and not the first?

Comment: My match url is http://subdomain.domain.it/aaa/aaa/aaa.html 3 slash after .it and at the end .html string.

Comment: Remember that `.` is a wild-card, you might've wanted to escape it - `(\\.html)`.

Comment: Or www.domain.it/aaa/aaa/aaa.html as before 3 slash afte .it string but with only domain and not subdomain. The url end with .html string

Comment: yes match with both url's but also with http://aaa.domain.it/aaa/aaa/aaa/aaa.html (another slash) my url must be with max 3 slash after .it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
"^http://[0-9a-zA-Z]+\\.domain\.it(/[^/]+?){3}.html$"
```

3 slashes max, and exclude `*.domain.it/`:

```
"^http://[0-9a-zA-Z]+\\.domain\.it(/[^/]+?){1,3}.html$"
```